# Changing the length of x axis in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have the following code.

> % Generate message signal
>
> t1 = -1:0.1:1;
>
> message_sig = rectpuls(t1);
>
> L = length(message_sig);
>
> figure(2)
>
> stairs(0:L-1:L, 'linewidth',1.5);
>
> axis([0 L -1 2]);
>
> title('Message Signal');

When i run this, the length of my x axis is from 0 to 20.
How can i reduce it to say 0 to 8, while plotting the same bit pattern. Because when i try modulating and add noise, the whole plot (noise modulated signal) is blue and needs to be zoomed alot to see accurately.

So can someone help me with a code that could solve this.

Comment: When I run this, my x axis goes from 0 to 7, did you forget to post some code

Comment: Oh Im sorry. I gave a different 't1' value. I've changed it now
t1 = -1:0.1:1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use `xlim([0,8])`, that will restrict the x-axis from going beyond 8, or edit your axis call to be `axis([0,8,-1,2])`

**UPDATE**

Assuming you have the image processing toolbox, it is really simple

```
in = [0,1,0];
imresize(in,[1,8],'nearest');
```

This will take that pattern and expand it to whatever dimension you want.

Comment: But see. According to my code, i get a 0 from 0:5, 1 from5:15 and again 0 from 15:20. But when i change my x axis limit to 0:8, then i only get a 0 from 0:5 and 1 from 5:8. What i really want is the same pulse shape/ bit pattern (0 1 0), but "shrunk" to say 0:8

Comment: you wanted it plotted like that or that data to actually be distributed in the same manner but just over 8 points?

Comment: No I want the same bit pattern (0 1 0) to be plotted over 8 points.

Comment: Okay give me a few minutes

Comment: No. Still having trouble there